# JSON WADL File to JavaScript to Catalogue Form

Tags: javascript

Hello Stackoverflowings.

I have a WADL URL. I know the format of the JSON. I was having issues connecting to the WADL which was a Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) error. My Java programming colleague fixed this. He is now on leave for 9 days and I am stuck. I cannot retrieve the necessary information or update as I am supposed to. I was promoted from Data Capturer now been trained as a Junior Developer. Could I please show my below code and ask for assistance?

```
/* This is the find party lite service
1.  findPartyLite Service
Description: Service used to find people using firstnames, lastnames, idnumbers and passport numbers to search with.
Note: Multiple results will be returned from this service if multiple people were found matching the given search criteria.
Service ULR: http://companyurl.blah.blah.com
{
    "typeHint":"person",
    "firstName":"James",
    "lastName":"Brown",
    "idNumber":"6509224000033",
    "passportNumber":null
}
# DictionaryName.FieldName # Field format
    OnBoardingANewEmployee_Employee_AcForms. OnboardingANewEmployee_Employee_Dic.setValue << SET
    OnBoardingANewEmployee_Employee_AcForms. OnboardingANewEmployee_Employee_Dic.getValue() [0];
*/


function findPartyLite() {
    var ltypeHint OnBoardingANewEmployee_Employee_AcForms.OnboardingANewEmployee_Employee_Dic.setValue(['typeHint']);
    var lfirstName OnBoardingANewEmployee_Employee_AcForms.OnboardingANewEmployee_Employee_Dic.setValue(['firstName']);
    var llastName OnBoardingANewEmployee_Employee_AcForms. OnboardingANewEmployee_Employee_Dic.setValue(['lastName']);
    var lidNumber OnBoardingANewEmployee_Employee_AcForms. OnboardingANewEmployee_Employee_Dic.setValue(['idNumber']);
    var lpassportNumber OnBoardingANewEmployee_Employee_AcForms. OnboardingANewEmployee_Employee_Dic.setValue(['passportNumber']);
    var loid OnBoardingANewEmployee_Employee_AcForms. OnboardingANewEmployee_Employee_Dic.setValue(['oid']);
    var findpartycheck1 = [ltypeHint,lfirstName,llastName,lidNumber,lpassportNumber]

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://companyurl.blah.blah.com";
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { 
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var listOfNames = ["typeHint", "firstName", "lastName", "idNumber", "passportNumber", "oid"];
            for (var i = 0; i < json.responseObjects.length; i++) { 
                listOfNames += ;
                listOfNames += + json.responseObjects[i].typeHint +
                listOfNames += + json.responseObjects[i].firstName +
                listOfNames += + json.responseObjects[i].lastName +
                listOfNames += + json.responseObjects[i].idNumber +
                listOfNames += + json.responseObjects[i].passportNumber +
                listOfNames += + json.responseObjects[i].oid +
                listOfNames += ;
            }

            var typeHint = json.responseObjects[i].typeHint.value;
            var firstName = json.responseObjects[i].firstName.value;
            var lastName = json.responseObjects[i].lastName.value;
            var idNumber = json.responseObjects[i].idNumber.value;
            var passportNumber = json.responseObjects[i].passportNumber.value;
            var oid = json.responseObjects[i].oid.value;
            var findpartycheck2 = [typeHint,firstName,lastName,idNumber,passportNumber,oid]

            if (JSON.stringify(findpartycheck1)==JSON.stringify(findpartycheck2)); { retrieveParty; }
                createEmployee;
        }
    }
 }
```

**From the Above I am trying to do the following:**

- Find person saved in JSON by WADL URL.
- Compare Captured First Name or Last Name or ID number or Passport Number and compare with the values from the JSON.
- If match found, call retrieveParty function
- If No match found, call createEmployee function.

The above code is what I have pieced together from 2 days solid reading. Could someone please point me in the right direction ? I would really appreciate, this is becoming fun learning!

Comment: What errors and/or results do you get with this code? I'm not a Java dev but I think that you shouldn't have space in `OnBoardingANewEmployee_Employee_AcForms. OnboardingANewEmployee_Employee_Dic.setValue(['typeHint']);` and similar lines (between dot and object)...

Comment: Hello Bozidar, thank you for your response. I have removed the space between the field names. I was following an example but can see now the space was left intentionally to highlight the field name. This morning I was receiving a "405" Error. With some googling I changed GET to POST and now I don't get any error. I presume I am connecting ok as I don't receive any errors.